# Angular SSR with firebase auth

Tags: angular, firebase, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I've tried to implement ssr in my angular firebase app, but stucked on auth part. What should be my approach for previously logged in users? I was thinking about sending id token as cookie to my express ssr backend and then if it is correct get data about user from it and then return logged in view while doing subscription on idToken via frontend and updating store data wihtout rerendering view. Are there any better or more correct approach to this subject? Internet really lack of good tutorials about auth with ssr.

Comment: I haven't tried this but the answer could be by using session cookies as per this document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies